# Can't put drive letter in file path in java

Tags: java, file, drive, letter

Hello I cannot put the `drive` letter in this:

```
File workingdir = new File(System.getenv("SystemDrive")+":/Users/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");
```

This is not working, however this is working:

```
File workingidr =new File("C:/Users/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");
```

I cannot hard code the `drive` letter, since it will run on multiple computers. Thank you for your help guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because `System.getenv("SystemDrive")` returns "C:" not "C", so change your code to this:

```
File workingdir = new File(System.getenv("SystemDrive")+"/Users/"+System.getProperty("user.name")+"/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default");
```

Also you could replace

```
System.getenv("SystemDrive")+"/Users/"+System.getProperty("user.name")
```

with this:

```
System.getProperty("user.home")
```

Hope this helped.